# Printing the number count with the collatz count: specific question

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code I wrote, where I want to find out how many iterations n are needed to reach x[n]=1 for a given input integer, and print that amount. (btw it is the collatz count). The code is:

```
x0 = int(input('Enter number:'))
while x0 > 1:
    print(x0, end=' ')
    if (x0 % 2):
        x0 = 3*x0 + 1
    else:
        x0 = x0//2

print(1, end=' ')
```

I want to know how many numbers are in the answer, but with this code I got all the answers. (Enter number:3 gives

```
3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

but I want my answer to look like this:

```
8
```

I thought putting `len()` after the `print` would work, but it didn't. How can I do this?

Comment: I edited your question to make the code clear. However, I am not sure about the indentation, which is critical in Python. Look it over and change it if this is not what you intended. Also, when I run the code as now shown and enter `3` I get a different printou: `3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1` which is the correct sequence for `3`.

Comment: From the output, it seems like the last print statement was within the `while` loop. (Although, yes it should be outside.) 
Note: expected output should be 8 not 14 for input 3.

Comment: Should it be 7 ? @TrebuchetMS

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, the output I get is: 3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1. So the answer should be 8.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thank you! As I'm new, I didn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a counter to your while loop:

```
x0 = int(input('Enter number:'))
counter = 1    # start at 1 b/c adding 1 after the loop
while x0 > 1:
    # increment so you count how often it loops
    counter += 1
    print(x0, end=' ')
    if (x0 % 2):
        x0 = 3*x0 + 1
    else:
        x0 = x0//2

print(1)  # print the 1 and newline

# and print the count as well
print(counter)
```

Output:

```
Enter number:20
20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
8
```

---

You could also collect all numbers in a list:

```
nums = []
while x0 > 1:
    nums.append(x0)
    if (x0 % 2):
        x0 = 3*x0 + 1
    else:
        x0 = x0//2

nums.append(1)

print(*nums)       # print the whole list here
print(len(nums))   # and it's length
```

---

Trivia: the longest collatz below 1,000,000 is 837799 with 525 steps to 1 && [xkcd.com take on Collatz Conjecture](https://xkcd.com/710/) - you find other limits at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Examples)